# jQuery datetimepicker not working in asp.net master page

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

In asp.net master page I added the following in head:

```
<link href="~/Content/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.css" rel="stylesheet" />
 <script src="<%: ResolveUrl("~/Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.min.js")%>"></script>
    <script src="<%: ResolveUrl("~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.24.min.js")%>"></script>
    <script src="<%: ResolveUrl("~/Scripts/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.js")%>"></script>
    <script src="<%: ResolveUrl("~/Scripts/jquery-ui-sliderAccess.js")%>"></script>
```

I've created a web page with master page and added the following within the contenct3:

```
<input runat="server" type="text" id="date_begin" value=""/>
```

And added the script within the head content as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function () {
    $('#date_begin,#date_end').datetimepicker();
});
</script>
```

But it shows an error in the console as follows:

> Uncaught TypeError: $(...).datetimepicker is not a function

Same thing I did without using master page and working fine.

Answer (score 0):

With jquery-ui you can just initialize datepicker like this :

```
$("#example").datepicker()
```

Try this link for more informations: http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/

Comment: datepicker() works. Problem with the datetimepicker() forms with master page.

Comment: Yes.But which jquery-ui file. There're few

Answer (score 0):

It is just "datepicker"

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<script>
  $( function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
  });
</script>
```

Official site: http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/

Make sure you use the newest jquery version too.

Comment: This is not showing the time. It shows only the date. I want date with the time.

Comment: Yeah, sorry. I saw that jquery is not supporting date and timepicker for some reason... So I found this http://www.jqueryrain.com/?lo_EWr2U looks quite nice. Have not tested it but it looks nice.